# How to Create a select multiple form with option?

Tags: struts2

I want to create a form like this :

```
<select name="selectedStatut" size="5" id="form_selectedStatut" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Editable</option>
    <option value="2">Traitement du systeme en cours</option>
    <option value="3">Diffusee au souscripteur</option>
    <option value="4">Diffusee au commercial</option>
    <option value="5">Diffusee au client</option>
    <option value="6">Supprimee</option>
</select>
```

I use the following code:

```
<s:select label="Statut" multiple="true" size="5"  list="#{'1':'Editable','2':'Traitement du systeme en cours','3':'Diffusee au souscripteur','4':'Diffusee au commercial','5':'Diffusee au client','6':'Supprimee'}"  name="selectedStatut">
                  </s:select>
```

But i get this form below:

```
<select name="selectedStatut" size="5" id="form_selectedStatut" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Editable">Editable</option>
    <option value="Traitement du systeme en cours">Traitement du systeme en cours</option>
    <option value="Diffusee au souscripteur">Diffusee au souscripteur</option>
    <option value="Diffusee au commercial">Diffusee au commercial</option>
    <option value="Diffusee au client">Diffusee au client</option>
    <option value="Supprimee">Supprimee</option>
</select>
```

Did i miss something ?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Excuse me ! I thought the first post did not work.

Comment: Sorry, i had a refresh problem on my Jboss server. The version on my war was not the good one.  Now i got the form as i need :

Comment: You should delete the duplicate post (either this or the other one) and I believe you should be able to answer your own question.  It is acceptable and you can accept your answer so that the community will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you need do this `listKey="key"` and `listValue="value"`:

```
<s:select label="Statut" multiple="true" size="5"  
       list="#{'1':'Editable','2':'Traitement du systeme en cours','3':'Diffusee au souscripteur','4':'Diffusee au commercial',
               '5':'Diffusee au client','6':'Supprimee'}"  
       name="selectedStatut" listKey="key" listValue="value"/>
```